# To display button for the particular clicked item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In my component i have one input field `i,e text area`. On clicking to particular `text area/ text box` i am showing the button like this:

[image]

This functionality is working fine

- **when i click on particular area i want show button(i,e SAVE) for that clicked text area only**.
- But on clicking **text area** the button(SAVE) is showing for all text areas as in the above image.

**CODE:**

**Template:**

```
 <div *ngFor="let loop of feeds">
    <label >
    <textarea                                
    (focus)="showChecklistAction = true" ></textarea>    

    <div *ngIf="showChecklistAction === true">
   <button style="margin:5px" (click)="updateSubtask(subtask)">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="site_btn no_bg_btn btn comment_btn bold" (click)="showChecklistAction = false; ">X</button>
</div></label>
   </div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

   feeds = [
    {
        name:'input1',
    },
    {
         name:'input2',
    }


  ]
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qadlcq?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach if you wanna keep the structure of your code the same is to use a template variable on the `*ngFor` element:

#### Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let loop of feeds" #input>
<label>
  <textarea (focus)="input.showChecklistAction = true" ></textarea>    

  <div *ngIf="input.showChecklistAction === true">
    <button style="margin:5px" (click)="updateSubtask(subtask)">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="site_btn no_bg_btn btn comment_btn bold" (click)="input.showChecklistAction = false; ">X</button>
  </div>

</label>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7emmz)

You could also use the `loop` instead of a template variable element but that will modify your binded value (the element in your feeds array will have the extra parameter `showChecklistAction`), so pick the approach that suits most.

*Note that the buttons stay visible when you unfocus the element, but I guess that's fine since you added the `X` button for that.*

Comment: Sorry i tried  this approach is not working for me.

Comment: I tried it on stackblitz it works fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7emmz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: On blur i need to hide the buttons will you please help me on that.

Comment: add `(blur)="input.showChecklistAction = false"` on the `<textarea>` element, I updated the StackBlitz

Comment: yes but on blur i am already calling the other function in my approach

Comment: In the `(blur)` add a semicolon between your function and the `input.showChecklistAction = false`

Answer (score 0):

You are taking an incorrect approach for creating a component, you are just looping over an array and creating multiple html markup, you need to create a "mytextareawithbuttons" component and then in your loop create the instances of your components,  this way each component will handle its own state.

Sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-okuqnp

Comment: According to my requirement i don't want to create a separate component for text area and button i should do it in the same component.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over a loop, setting **showChecklistAction = true** shall show button controls for all array items. What you need is to track each individual array items to show / hide button controls.

One approach could be to modify your **feeds** array and add a field **isFocused**, like this..

```js
       feeds = [
    {
        name:'input1',
        isFocused:false
    },
    {
         name:'input2',
         isFocused:false
    }
]
```

Your component html code will change like this

```html
   
   <div *ngFor="let loop of feeds">
    <label >
    <textarea                                
    (focus)="loop.isFocused = true" ></textarea>    
    
    <div *ngIf="loop.isFocused === true">
   <button style="margin:5px" (click)="updateSubtask(subtask)">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="site_btn no_bg_btn btn comment_btn bold" (click)="loop.isFocused = false; ">X</button>
</div></label>
   </div>
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7gvwu) link.

Thanks.